# Working with general vector spaces is getting really tough, how to make it easier?

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm in my second linear algebra class at university and dealing with vector spaces that aren't defined instead of $\Bbb R^2$ or matrices or polynomials is getting pretty tough.

Any tips on how to approach problems like "Let $\Bbb L: \Bbb V \to \Bbb V$ be a linear mapping _______, prove the linear mapping $\Bbb M: \Bbb V \to \Bbb W$ is ______"?

Comment: Sometimes you can pick a basis and work in coordinates. Sometimes you need to choose a basis that satisfies the appropriate property. In the remaining $70\%$ of the cases you have to be proficient in the subject.

Comment: You are going to have to learn to abstract. *This* is precisely why advanced courses in mathematics usually expect you to have taken that second linear algebra class.

Comment: In my experience students beginning proof writing have more difficulty with logic and the general structure of a proof than they do with the material.  It's hard to give any advice without either seeing a specific example or writing many pages. One piece of advice: you need to become very proficient in knowing how to *start* and *end* proofs.

Comment: For example, if the problem is of the form "Let $S = \{v_1, v_2, v_3\}$ be vectors satisfying property X. Prove that $S$ is a linearly independent set."  You need to *automatically* write down: "Suppose $a_1, a_2, a_3 \in \mathbb{R}$ with $a_1v_1 + a_2v_2 + a_3v_3 = 0$. Then.... (insert math here, somehow using the property).  Thus $a_1 = a_2 = a_3 = 0$.  So $S$ is a linearly independent set."  If you can figure out how to correctly write the first and last sentence of your proof, you are often halfway finished (at least for simple introductory proofs.)

Comment: @JairTaylor Haha yeah I kinda figured that one out for linear independence, are you saying there's something like that for every other type of proof then basically?

Comment: @ming Pretty much! At least for many of the proof questions you get in a first linear algebra course.  Later on, when the basic logic is second-nature, the "real math" becomes more difficult (and more interesting.)

Comment: I see now it is your second linear algebra course, so maybe you have already got to the more interesting parts...